# Flutter: Get local IP address on Android

Tags: flutter, dart, network-programming, ip-address

How do I get the local IP address of my (Android) device in Flutter?
This should be

- the local IP address I get assigned via DHCP by my router when connected to WIFI
- the local IP address in the VPN network assigned by my VPN server (not the global IP address by the VPN server itself) if connected to VPN
- the global IP when connected via cellular

Comment: take a look at these plugins: https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity  https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/get_ip

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved it like this for now, but if you have a better solution, that would be deligthful:

```
static Future<String> getLocalIpAddress() async {
    final interfaces = await NetworkInterface.list(type: InternetAddressType.IPv4, includeLinkLocal: true);

    try {
      // Try VPN connection first
      NetworkInterface vpnInterface = interfaces.firstWhere((element) => element.name == "tun0");
      return vpnInterface.addresses.first.address;
    } on StateError {
      // Try wlan connection next
      try {
        NetworkInterface interface = interfaces.firstWhere((element) => element.name == "wlan0");
        return interface.addresses.first.address;
      } catch (ex) {
        // Try any other connection next
        try {
          NetworkInterface interface = interfaces.firstWhere((element) => !(element.name == "tun0" || element.name == "wlan0"));
          return interface.addresses.first.address;
        } catch (ex) {
          return null;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Need: `import 'dart:io';`