# How can I find out the ip-addresses of my smartphone? ipv4 and ipv6. Flutter. Dart

Tags: android, flutter, sockets, dart, ip-address

It's easy to find out my ip address in Kotlin language:

```
var dgs=DatagramSocket()
dgs.connect(InetAddress.getByName("2023::1"),8888)
var stringForTextView="localAddress.hostName: ${dgs.localAddress.hostName}"
dgs.close()
```

I cannot find method "connect" for RawDatagramSocket in flutter/dart.

Maybe there is another way to find out the ip-addresses of my smartphone?

I know one:

```
http.get(Uri.parse("https://ifconfig.us"),
     headers: {"User-Agent": "curl"}).then((value) {
     setState(() {
        myIpAddress = value.body;
     });
});
```

But I don't want to bother third party servers. And rely on them.
Especially when we are in a private address space.

Another strange thing.
I can get my ip address by execute

```
adb shell ip route get 8.8.8.8
```

But I cannot do it by Runtime.getRuntime.exec("ip route get 8.8.8.8") in java(kotlin) or Process.run in dart/flutter. Permissions denied. Even I have INTERNET, ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE in AndroidManifest.xml.
'Cannot bind netlink socket: Permission denied'

ConnectBot app from Google Play Store can execute "ip route get 8.8.8.8".
Mine can't. With the same network permissions.

Any suggestions?

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63514434/flutter-get-local-ip-address-on-android

Comment: NetworkInterface.list().then((value) {value.forEach ((address) {myAddresses=myAddresses + "\n" + address.address}) It give me list of two of three ip-addresses.  How to determine which of them is can be used for connection to smartphone? On kotlin(or java) we can simulate udp socket connection to any internet address without real connection attempt. And get local address from socket. Most likely this will be a valid address. I don't know of any other method to determine this. Or how to execute shell command 'ip route get 8.8.8.8'.

Comment: I've just tested my app on Android 10 (API 29) . And  Process.run('ip', ['route', 'get', '8.8.8.8']) works fine! The same code not works on Android 11(API 30)! What has been changed?

Comment: founded this package https://pub.dev/packages/process_run which run shell command, it also support android.

Comment: tested the above package on android 10 device, able to run limited number of UNIX shell command https://pastebin.com/jZgKDTkp here is the code which I ran to test the package. "ip route get 8.8.8.8" works to get local ip, you can test it on android 11 if it runs, if it doesn't run it may be because of android 11 security feature.